# Is there a Data Structure like Binary Decision Diagrams for Non-Binary Functions

Tags: data-structures

Binary Decision Diagrams (BDD) take a set of binary variables $x_1, x_2,..., x_n$ as input.

Is there a data structure similar to BDDs where each variable takes more than two values? Each variable's values should be independent of every other variable. For example, $x_i$ could be assigned the three values $\{0,1,2\}$ and $x_j$ could be assigned the four values $\{0,1,2,3\}$, where $i \ne j$.

Comment: Yes, multi-valued decision diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

Yup.  A BDD is just an acyclic finite-state automaton (DFA) that accepts a language $L \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$.  It represents the function $f(x)= 1$ if $x \in L$ or $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin L$.

You can generalize this to allow an acyclic finite-state automaton over a language over a different alphabet, or indeed, a language $L \subseteq \Sigma_1 \times \cdots \times \Sigma_n$ where $\Sigma_i$ is the set of valid values for $x_i$.  Everything carries over.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there a name to this class of DFAs? Specifically I'm interested in which BDD algorithms can be used (perhaps with modification).

Also, I believe a single transition can increment by more than one. Consider the transition from $x_1$ to $x_3$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram#/media/File:BDD_Variable_Ordering_Good.svg).

Comment: @HiDefender, good point.  I don't know of any special name for it (other than "BDD").  I believe all the standard operations work (e.g., via the product construction), but I suggest you work out the details and if you get stuck on any specific one, you could post a question asking about that one.